# Why ClassCastException?

Tags: java, exception

```
package com.lean.ssm.chapter2.proxy1;

public interface HelloWorld {

    void sayHelloWorld();

}
package com.lean.ssm.chapter2.proxy1;

public class HelloWorldImp {
    public void sayHelloWorld() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }

}
package com.lean.ssm.chapter2.proxy1;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

public class JdkProxyExample implements InvocationHandler {

    private Object target = null; 

    public Object bind(Object target) {  
        this.target = target;
        return
                Proxy.newProxyInstance(target.getClass().getClassLoader(),
                        target.getClass().getInterfaces(), this);
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("进入代理逻辑方法");
        System.out.println("调度真实对象之前的服务");
        Object obj = method.invoke(target, args);
        System.out.println("调度真实对象之后的服务");
        return obj;
    }
}
package com.lean.ssm.chapter2.proxy1;

public class ProxyTest {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            testJdkProxy();}
        private static void testJdkProxy() {
            JdkProxyExample jdk = new JdkProxyExample();
            HelloWorld proxy = (HelloWorld) jdk.bind(new HelloWorldImp());
            proxy.sayHelloWorld();}

}
```

Console:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to com.lean.ssm.chapter2.proxy1.HelloWorld
    at com.lean.ssm.chapter2.proxy1.ProxyTest.testJdkProxy(ProxyTest.java:8)
    at com.lean.ssm.chapter2.proxy1.ProxyTest.main(ProxyTest.java:5)

Comment: Maybe you need to provide more infomation about "MyInterceptor", "HelloWorld" and so on.

Comment: Please provide us [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help

Comment: The code looks fine. We need to see `HelloWorld`, `HelloWorldImp`, `MyInterceptor` and `InterceptorJdkProxy`.

Comment: Your updated `HelloWorldImp` does not implement `HelloWorld`. Add that and your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

`ClassCastException` disappears when you make `HelloWorldImp` implement `HelloWorld`:

```
class HelloWorldImp implements HelloWorld {
    @Override
    public void sayHelloWorld() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

The problem is in the `bind(Object)` method.

According to [Proxy.newProxyInstance(ClassLoader, Class[], InocationHandler) docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#newProxyInstance(java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.Class[],%20java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler)). The second parameter is

> the list of interfaces for the proxy class to implement

Since `HelloWorldImp` had not implement any, the `target.getClass().getInterfaces()` call returned empty array and generated proxy did not implement `HelloWorld` interface. So the cast in

```
HelloWorld proxy = (HelloWorld) jdk.bind(new HelloWorldImp());
```

failed

Answer (score -1):

if you typecast an object of class A into an object of class B and they are not compatible type then you get cast exception case.
eg.

```
Object obj = Integer.valueOf(100);
String value = (String)obj;  // ClassCastException occurs.
```

Comment: OP is aware of that. OP is asking *why* the classes aren't compatible.